# CS50- Lab4- Volume- For Loop Vs Array for header copy

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, runtime, cs50

I have successfully complied the volume.c with below code to copy the header from input to output file. However, I have seen uint8_t header[HEADER_SIZE] to be typically used in the solutions I checked later.

**My Version**

```
// TODO: Copy header from input file to output file  
 uint8_t headers;
    for (int i = 0; i < HEADER_SIZE; i ++)
    {
        fread(&headers, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, input);
        fwrite(&headers, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, output);
    }
```

**Typical Solution**

```
// TODO: Copy header from input file to output file
    uint8_t header[HEADER_SIZE];
    fread(&header, sizeof(header), 1, input);
    fwrite(&header, sizeof(header), 1, output);
```

Other than the slightly increased run time, what are the other drawbacks with my approach?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken slightly increased run time is an understatement it is HIGHLY increased run time because tis looping each header and making it more complex to read. Whereas the typical solution is much more efficient and stores it into an array making it more accessible and easier to read.